# The module has not been deployed in java NetBeans, GlassFish

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

The description of the problem:
I am creating an EJB(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T6f3UGBypYY&t=472s using this Tutorial) and after trying to deploy the following error occurs:

In the EJB class:

```
GlassFish Server 4.1.1, deploy, null, false
```

C:\Users\Karol\Documents\NetBeansProjects\xxx-Main-EJB\nbproject\build-impl.xml:934: The module has not been deployed.

In the GlassFish Server:

```
WARNING: Can not start bundle file:/C:/Program%20Files/glassfish-4.1.1/glassfish/modules/core.jar because it is not contained in the list of installed bundles.
```

What I already did?

I have changed the DOMAIN.XML in the following way:

```
 <network-listener port="8060" protocol="http-listener-1" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
          <network-listener port="8061" protocol="http-listener-2" transport="tcp" name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool"></network-listener>
          <network-listener port="4848" protocol="admin-listener" transport="tcp" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool"></network-listener>
```

(I have changed the ports)

I try to update the glassfish, I have restarted the computer, I turn off antivirus, I restarted the computer, I beg my program to work properly, I have created the new one project and still nothing.

Comment: Have you tried a "build with dependencies" and have you checked your Java SE and Java EE Versions in your pom?

Comment: I am using a NetBeans IDE 8.2 and I have java version  8 (so i guess everything is ok) 

about build with dependencies I did not, because i still don't have main class

Comment: (To be more specific I am using JAVA EE 7 and Java SE 8 ) but for example in JAVA JPA CRUDE everything works properly

Comment: Every time I build a new project (like a maven) I need to go to my pom and change my java se version. GlassFish 4.1.1 does not work on java as 1.7. Once you are sure that is correct, right click on your project and build with dependencies. This will update the jar files in your libraries. If all of that is done and working then it can only be one other thing. Do this first and then we can move on to higher complexity trouble shooting.

Comment: I don't have option "build widh dependiences" -> https://imgur.com/a/XdAXQ

Thanks, for trying to help!:)

Comment: It is not clear the exact configuration of your project, but we can keep going. Lets look else where. Do you have a WEB-INF folder? Does it contain a glassfish-resources.xml?

Comment: I am working on java SE 1.8.
I do not, I guess i don't need it because I'm not working in web-services, or am I wrong?

It looks like that: http://screenshot.sh/mFd8swWrzZQe4

Comment: There isn't a screenshot when I click on your link, however, another route we can go is in your proxy settings you could try selecting "No Proxy" I'm trying to think of all possible avenues this could be coming from